# What's the clean way to rollback a hung OBIEE 11.1.1.7 installation

Tags: obiee

Looks like using the deinstall option would wipe out the entire HOME & BI cluster.
While we are trying to restore down to the 11.1.1.6 previous installation.

Windows platform. We were using the software-only in-place upgrade.

---

[Solved] The cleanest way, turns out, is to repeat the process multiple times while eliminating the reasons causing it to stick, one-by-one. It then rolls forward nicely, simply logging "this has been already upgraded". Also noticed that some of the Java installs have the sticky "finish" button - which is resolved by simply killing the javaw process. Happened on 2 out of 4 GUI installation steps during the upgrade.

Comment: This question might be better asked on ServerFault.

Comment: Submitted as well. Although they didn't even have the OBIEE tag there.